# How to close a thread nested inside a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, nested, abort

I have a thread nested inside another thread in my code.  in my closing event, I use `upperThread.Abort()` to close the upper thread.  however, my code gets hung up.  I believe this is because my `lowerThread()` is still running.  how can I close the lower (nested) thread to close the application properly?

Comment: `Thread.Abort()` is *not safe* and you should not be using it in new code.

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because you seem to have some false beliefs about how threads work. Threads do not "nest". There is a difference between worker threads and the UI thread, but that difference is not usually expressed as a "nesting" relationship. More generally, cdhowie is absolutely right; if you're writing thread.Abort, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. If you need to shut a thread down then come up with a signal mechanism whereby one thread can shut another down politely.

Comment: `Thread.Abort` makes the baby jeebus weep. Use `Task`, please.

Comment: @EricLippert thank you for the heads up.  this should point me to the right direction.

Comment: this example gives me the false belief.  however, I do see a thread that starts another thread. http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server.  how do you shut down both of them?

Comment: @hoangnguyen: You find better sample code. That code is not very well written, and does not permit the listener or client threads to be shut down remotely.

Comment: Well of course one thread starts another thread; what else would start a thread in user code?  But that doesn't make the "old" thread somehow the "owner" of a new thread. Threads are owned by their process, not by another thread. You shut down both threads by coming up with a mechanism whereby all the threads in the process politely agree on when it is time to shut down; if you're writing programs with multiple threads then that's something you have to know how to do.

Comment: The easiest way, by some considerable margin, is to simply terminate the application.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Abort()` is not recommended but might still be required in some rare cases.

Here a simple example:

```
var parent = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    Thread child = null;
    try
    {
        child = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            // do stuff
        }));
        child.Start();
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        if (child != null && child.IsAlive)
        {
            // Abort child when parent is aborted
            child.Abort();
        }
    }
}));
parent.Start();
parent.Abort();
```

Read more about ThreadAbortException on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Inside upper thread you can catch `ThreadAbortException`. It is thrown when thread is aborted. Then in catch statement you can abort your inner thread